# Outlook Addin - setSelectedDataAsync puts cursor at the beginning of inserted content

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to insert some URLs into email body at the cursor position as guided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/insert-data-in-the-body). I am using `setSelectedDataAsync` to insert the URL. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.Body?view=outlook-js-preview#setselecteddataasync-data--options--callback-) for `setSelectedDataAsync` mentions

> After insertion, the cursor is placed at the end of the inserted
> content.

Problem is my cursor position doesn't change even after inserting URLs. Am i missing something here?

```js
Office.onReady(info => {
      "use strict";
      if (info.host === Office.HostType.Outlook) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).ready(function() {
              GetBookmarksFromDB();
            });
          }
        });

      function GetBookmarksFromDB() {
        let urlRepo = ["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL", "www.google.com", "fifa.com"];
        $("#urlInsert").html();
        $.each(urlRepo, (i, v) => {
          $("#urlInsert").append(
            `<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center p-1">${v}<span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"><i class="insertLink fa fa-plus"></i></li></span>`
          );
        });
        $(".insertLink").on("click", function() {
          let url = $(this)
            .parents("li")
            .text();
          insertBookmarksIntoEmail(url);
        });
      }

      function insertBookmarksIntoEmail(url) {
        let item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
        item.body.getTypeAsync(function(result) {
          if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
            write(result.error.message);
          } else {
            // Successfully got the type of item body.
            // Set data of the appropriate type in body.
            if (result.value == Office.MailboxEnums.BodyType.Html) {
              // Body is of HTML type.
              // Specify HTML in the coercionType parameter
              // of setSelectedDataAsync.
              item.body.setSelectedDataAsync(
                `<a href="${url}">${url}</a>`, {
                  coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html
                },
                function(asyncResult) {
                  if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                    write(asyncResult.error.message);
                  } else {
                    // Successfully set data in item body.
                    // Do whatever appropriate for your scenario,
                    // using the arguments var3 and var4 as applicable.
                  }
                }
              );
            } else {
              // Body is of text type.
              item.body.setSelectedDataAsync(
                url, {
                  coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Text,
                  asyncContext: {
                    var3: 1,
                    var4: 2
                  }
                },
                function(asyncResult) {
                  if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                    write(asyncResult.error.message);
                  } else {
                    // Successfully set data in item body.
                    // Do whatever appropriate for your scenario,
                    // using the arguments var3 and var4 as applicable.
                  }
                }
              );
            }
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: Which client (platform) are you using for the above (OWA, win32, MAC, iOS, android) ?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. We were able to reproduce it for OWA. It has been put on our backlog. We, unfortunately, have no timelines to share at this point.